# How to create a (Nested?) csv file loader for Keras/Tensorflow Machine Learning?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras

So I am new to the field of ML and I made some simple programs to test out a neural network ( Image recognition ).

Now I have a new classification problem where each datapoint is a CSV file by itself (instead of 1 csv file being the entire dataset ). How would I go about preparing this data for a neural network like "keras.Sequential()"

Here is 1 file from the dataset. ( I have 10 classes for the classification problem and each class has 100 such files as data points )

https://github.com/Harshahi/TestDATA/blob/main/OpenBCI-RAW-2020-11-18_09-42-50.csv

Comment: does one file contain multiple rows which all belong to the same class or is the whole file a single datapoint? you say that but after opening this file seem to be a classical dataframe, containing independent rows, or is that sequential? Also you should add what have you tried so far.

Comment: Hey Ruli, So far I have cleaned the CSV file ( same number of rows using pandas ) ( do I remove the first few lines of text too?). My problem is that every example I have seen uses the CSV file as the database instead of the datapoint. How do I achieve this?